# rsyslog config to merge multiple lines coming via imuxsock

Tags: systemd, rsyslog

I have a web service that writes its output to stdout and is managed by systemd. The systemd config sends stdout to syslog. The problem I have is that multiline messages are split into multiple syslog entries. This is a problem specially with exception stacktraces. Is there any way to configure rsyslog to merge those into one entry? I found some solutions using the `readMode` property of `imfile` which does exactly what I need but in my case i'm receiving the data directly from the default `imuxsock`.

The test I'm using is running

```
echo -e "<<hello\n\tsecond\n\tthird\nnew message>>" | logger -t my-tag
```

This generates

```
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag: <<hello
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag:    second
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag:    third
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag: new message>>
```

But I want to get is

```
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag: <<hello
    second
    third
May 16 17:06:46 host my-tag: new message>>
```

Is this possible?
The behaviour can be described as mode 2 in `imfile`'s readMode

> 2 - indented (new log messages start at the beginning of a line. If a line starts with a space or tab “t” it is part of the log message before it)

With the caveat that because it's not static data like imfile consumes, there would need to be a timer, 1s or something, where if no new data has been received, we assume that the log entry has terminated

Comment: It might to be simpler to just have your web service use its own dedicated log files directly, like for example apache does. If you want to have timestamped lines you can pipe through a utility like `ts`, or write a small awk script, and use `logrotate` to manage your logs. Or use rsyslog's `imfile` to read the file as a separate stream.

Comment: @meuh i thought of that but I don't want to do that because i would end up with two files, one for the logger output and one for the stdout output. Or i would need to have two different processes writing to the same file, which is always tricky. Dumping all to stdout at least converges all the output and it is all handled by syslog

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [omprog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html) rsyslog module to try to stitch the data lines together. For example, the configuration

```
$ModLoad omprog
:syslogtag, isequal, "my-tag:" action(type="omprog"
    binary="/bin/myprog" output="/var/log/myoutput")
```

would run the program `/bin/myprog` and pass through to it all input with the `my-tag` tag.  Any output from the program would be saved to file `/var/log/myoutput`.

The example program below uses an `awk` script that prints lines using `printf` without a terminating newline. Input that has a message part that begins with a tab (which here is escaped by `rsyslog` to octal `#011`), would similarly be printed. A newline would be printed just before any input that does not have a tab, and so is a new message.  I leave you to add a flushing timeout.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
/my-tag: #011/{
     i = index($0,"#011")
     printf "\n\t%s",substr($0,i+4)
     next
}
{    if(NR>1)printf "\n"; fflush();
     printf "%s",$0
}'
```

Note this is gnu awk (gawk), which has a `fflush()` command. Otherwise you may need something like the `stdbuf` command to stop buffering.